# Does FileStream.ReadAsync sometimes complete synchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Give this a try. Setup a new Windows Forms application with a single button and the following code for the button click event:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var file = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\Sample.txt"))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        int read = await file.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Debug.Assert(threadId != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Then run the application and click the button rapidly. If your experience is anything like mine you’ll find that sometimes it works as expected, however, other times the `Debug.Assert` will fail.

Based on my understanding of `ConfigureAwait` [as explained on Stephen Cleary’s blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), passing `false` for `continueOnCapturedContext` should instruct the task to not sync back to the “main” context (UI thread in this case) and that execution should continue on the thread pool.

Why then would the assert fail randomly? I can only assume that `ReadAsync` will sometimes not complete on a background thread, i.e. it will complete synchronously.

This behavior is in line with KB 156932 - [Asynchronous Disk I/O Appears as Synchronous on Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156932):

> Most I/O drivers (disk, communications, and others) have special case
>   code where, if an I/O request can be completed "immediately," the
>   operation will be completed and the ReadFile or WriteFile function
>   will return TRUE. In all ways, these types of operations appear to be
>   synchronous. For a disk device, typically, an I/O request can be
>   completed "immediately" when the data is cached in memory.

Are my assumptions and test application correct? Can the `ReadAsync` method sometimes complete synchronously? Is there a way to guarantee that execution will always continue on a background thread?

This issue is wreaking havoc on my application which uses COM objects that require me to know which thread is executing at all times.

Windows 7 64-bit, .NET 4.5.1

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't opening the file in asynchronous mode?

Comment: I found no change to the behavior described above when the file is opened using a `FileStream` overload that specifies "asynchronous mode".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the ReadAsync method sometimes complete synchronously?

Yes. This is not uncommon due to buffers both at the OS level and within the .NET stream types.

> Is there a way to guarantee that execution will always continue on a background thread?

If you always want code to execute on a thread pool thread, then use `Task.Run`:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var file = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\Sample.txt"))
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    int read = await file.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      Debug.Assert(threadId != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
}
```

`ConfigureAwait` is an optimization hint, not a command to move to a background thread. `ConfigureAwait` has no effect if the operation is already completed. In this case, `await` follows a ["fast path"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/15/async-ctp-refresh-design-changes.aspx) that essentially means it continues synchronously, so any `ConfigureAwait` hints are ignored.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Am I alone then in thinking `ConfigureAwait` is a bit misleading? Nothing I found on MSDN suggested to me that it was a hint more than a fact. For example, your code sample uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the `Task.Run`. What guarantee do I have that `Task.Run` will complete on the intended context any more than `FileStream.ReadAsync` does using the same approach?

Comment: My code would work exactly the same without the `ConfigureAwait` calls; it would just be slightly less efficient. It's what goes *inside* the `Task.Run` that is guaranteed to run on a thread pool thread, not any continuations.

Answer (score 2):

If the file read completes synchronously before the call to await, I am fairly certain that none of the async compiler magic happens and execution continues synchronously on the calling thread. I would use `Task.Run(() => file.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))` to queue the work to the thread pool if I wanted to guarantee that it starts on a thread pool thread.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `await` on a `Task`, if the task is already completed the code will execute synchronously. Then calling `ConfigureAwait` on that task will make no difference as there will be no other thread involved.

Sounds like if the data is in memory (because you are reading the same file repeatedly) `file.ReadAsync` can complete synchronously, and hence it will complete on the same thread.